# Do elements drawn outside the clip plane affect OpenGL performance?

Tags: performance, opengl

OpenGL Question:
I have something to ask about **clip space transformation**. I am reading an online tutorial and it says that everything you draw outside the clip space will be clipped. When it come to this, does the elements outside the clip space affects the performance or not? Because it will not be drawn and thus it doesn't affect.

Assuming that it will affect performance and in case of 2d game like super mario, I am thinking about not to draw the elements outside the clip space to achieve better performance.
 Please clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL has only a certain amount of knowledge about your scene and will clip very late in the pipeline. It can't apply a broad phase test. Assuming you can, you should.

Supposing you had a model with 30,000 triangles, OpenGL would transform each and every one of those 30,000 triangles before considering clipping. If you know something as simple as the bounding sphere for the model it's possible you could see that the whole thing is completely outside of the frustum in a single test and save almost 30,000 extra bits of effort.

In a 2d game like Mario what this usually means is using the scroll position to index into the map and to generate geometry only for potentially visible tiles and sprites that are within the visible area.

For the map that will generally just men figuring out the (x, y) of one corner and then generating geometry for the known width and height of the screen so it means discarding the vast majority of the geometry with zero processing.

For the sprites, this is generally why in those sort of games you often see enemies reset to their starting position if you walk a little way from them and then walk back: they're added to the active list based on a map location trigger and removed when you walk far enough away. While not active, no mutable storage is afforded to them.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, thanks for the clarification. So it is without use if i design the code not to draw elements outside the clip space.

Comment: It'll likely still be used unless your geometry is exactly aligned with screen edges. Generally speaking, you use knowledge you have of  the relationship between geometry that OpenGL is never given to spot that 90+% of it definitely isn't on screen without having to break it down, then pass whatever possibly _may_ be on screen to OpenGL to do the completely thorough tests on.